# Nodejs install/use failure Raspberry Pi4B

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I have tried installing Nodejs now several ways, but i always get the error when trying to execute a node command, that node doesn't exist, i would be glad for your guys help

[Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btAq7.png)

I tried Running Node + npm but it doesn't work even though installations reportedly are successful